# Intercepting search bar query in Shopify Online Store

Tags: shopify, customization, shopify-app, searchbar

I am building a Shopify app. The app needs to intercept search queries of the Shopify online store search bar. The problem I am facing is where to start with:

1. Should the code be written in the Shopify app to intercept the search. If it is indeed written there where would i find the file to write the code to intercept the search bar of the online store.
2. OR do I need to create a custom Shopify theme to intercept the Shopify store search bar. if so then how will i compensate for different themes installed by users.
3. Is there any other method to do this task in my Shopify app such as using ajax.

I have build a test Shopify app but could not find anywhere to write the code to modify Store.

I tried cloning the dawn theme to intercept the store searchbar but changes to any tag related to search bar does not work.

So I don't know where to start with my task.